# Updating a SQL Statement returns no records when newly added table has no data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have recently been told to add a field for comments. Since theses comments are meant for accounting, I have created a new table. CITCommentID, CITComment, DealID, CITCurrentComment are the fields within the table. I have to update a SQL statement that selects multiple items from multiple tables to display to the user. The problem that I'm having is since there is no data within that table yet, I'm unable to retrieve the other information. Here is my statement.

```
SELECT vl.dealid, 
       stocknumber, 
       dealnumber, 
       newdeal, 
       archived, 
       dealershipname, 
       salespersonnumber, 
       customername, 
       grossprofit, 
       dealdate, 
       make, 
       model, 
       newused, 
       amtfinanced, 
       category, 
       bankname, 
       customernumber, 
       finame, 
       status, 
       locationname, 
       datereceived, 
       comment, 
       titled, 
       changedby, 
       funded, 
       contractsreturned, 
       citcomment DateChanged 
FROM   tvehiclelog vl 
       JOIN tcustomer cu 
         ON cu.customerid = vl.customerid 
       JOIN tbank b 
         ON b.bankid = vl.bankid 
       JOIN tmake m 
         ON m.makeid = vl.makeid 
       JOIN tdealerships d 
         ON d.dealershipid = vl.dealershipid 
       JOIN tsalesperson sp 
         ON sp.salespersonid = vl.salespersonid 
       JOIN tmodel ml 
         ON ml.modelid = vl.modelid 
       JOIN tinternallocations il 
         ON il.internallocationid = vl.internallocationid 
       JOIN tvehiclecomments vcc 
         ON vl.commentid = vcc.commentid 
       JOIN tcontractsintransitcomments citc    --This is new join
         ON vl.citcommentid = citc.citcommentid --CommentID relates to the table vl 
       JOIN tfimanagers fi 
         ON fi.fimanagerid = vl.fimanagerid 
WHERE  vl.dealid = 5224 
GROUP  BY vl.dealid, 
          [stocknumber], 
          [newdeal], 
          [archived], 
          [customername], 
          [dealdate], 
          [amtfinanced], 
          [bounced], 
          [comment], 
          [locationname], 
          [daysout], 
          [datereceived], 
          [dealnumber], 
          [dealershipname], 
          [salespersonnumber], 
          [grossprofit], 
          [make], 
          [model], 
          [newused], 
          [category], 
          [bankname], 
          [customernumber], 
          [finame], 
          [status], 
          [locationname], 
          [datereceived], 
          [comment], 
          [titled], 
          [changedby], 
          [funded], 
          [contractsreturned], 
          [datechanged], 
          citcomment 
ORDER  BY [datechanged] ASC;
```

I need this statement to return results even if the there are no comments that relate to the record. Since this is a new table with no comments in it, it still needs to show the other information. I'm still learning MSSQL and I don't know all the tricks yet. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to a `LEFT JOIN.` A left join means that the select statement will return results even if there are no comments that relate to the records in the results.

```
LEFT JOIN tcontractsintransitcomments citc    --This is new join
ON vl.citcommentid = citc.citcommentid --CommentID relates to the table vl
```

This is the full SQL:

```
SELECT vl.dealid, 
       stocknumber, 
       dealnumber, 
       newdeal, 
       archived, 
       dealershipname, 
       salespersonnumber, 
       customername, 
       grossprofit, 
       dealdate, 
       make, 
       model, 
       newused, 
       amtfinanced, 
       category, 
       bankname, 
       customernumber, 
       finame, 
       status, 
       locationname, 
       datereceived, 
       comment, 
       titled, 
       changedby, 
       funded, 
       contractsreturned, 
       citcomment DateChanged 
FROM   tvehiclelog vl 
       JOIN tcustomer cu 
         ON cu.customerid = vl.customerid 
       JOIN tbank b 
         ON b.bankid = vl.bankid 
       JOIN tmake m 
         ON m.makeid = vl.makeid 
       JOIN tdealerships d 
         ON d.dealershipid = vl.dealershipid 
       JOIN tsalesperson sp 
         ON sp.salespersonid = vl.salespersonid 
       JOIN tmodel ml 
         ON ml.modelid = vl.modelid 
       JOIN tinternallocations il 
         ON il.internallocationid = vl.internallocationid 
       JOIN tvehiclecomments vcc 
         ON vl.commentid = vcc.commentid 
       LEFT JOIN tcontractsintransitcomments citc    --This is new join
         ON vl.citcommentid = citc.citcommentid --CommentID relates to the table vl 
       JOIN tfimanagers fi 
         ON fi.fimanagerid = vl.fimanagerid 
WHERE  vl.dealid = 5224 
GROUP  BY vl.dealid, 
          [stocknumber], 
          [newdeal], 
          [archived], 
          [customername], 
          [dealdate], 
          [amtfinanced], 
          [bounced], 
          [comment], 
          [locationname], 
          [daysout], 
          [datereceived], 
          [dealnumber], 
          [dealershipname], 
          [salespersonnumber], 
          [grossprofit], 
          [make], 
          [model], 
          [newused], 
          [category], 
          [bankname], 
          [customernumber], 
          [finame], 
          [status], 
          [locationname], 
          [datereceived], 
          [comment], 
          [titled], 
          [changedby], 
          [funded], 
          [contractsreturned], 
          [datechanged], 
          citcomment 
ORDER  BY [datechanged] ASC;
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. I thought I had a left join but definitely did not. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT vl.dealid, 
       stocknumber, 
       dealnumber, 
       newdeal, 
       archived, 
       dealershipname, 
       salespersonnumber, 
       customername, 
       grossprofit, 
       dealdate, 
       make, 
       model, 
       newused, 
       amtfinanced, 
       category, 
       bankname, 
       customernumber, 
       finame, 
       status, 
       locationname, 
       datereceived, 
       comment, 
       titled, 
       changedby, 
       funded, 
       contractsreturned, 
       citcomment DateChanged 
FROM   tvehiclelog vl 
       JOIN tcustomer cu 
         ON cu.customerid = vl.customerid 
       JOIN tbank b 
         ON b.bankid = vl.bankid 
       JOIN tmake m 
         ON m.makeid = vl.makeid 
       JOIN tdealerships d 
         ON d.dealershipid = vl.dealershipid 
       JOIN tsalesperson sp 
         ON sp.salespersonid = vl.salespersonid 
       JOIN tmodel ml 
         ON ml.modelid = vl.modelid 
       JOIN tinternallocations il 
         ON il.internallocationid = vl.internallocationid 
       JOIN tvehiclecomments vcc 
         ON vl.commentid = vcc.commentid 
       LEFT JOIN tcontractsintransitcomments citc    
         ON vl.citcommentid = citc.citcommentid 
       JOIN tfimanagers fi 
         ON fi.fimanagerid = vl.fimanagerid 
WHERE  vl.dealid = 5224 
GROUP  BY vl.dealid, 
          [stocknumber], 
          [newdeal], 
          [archived], 
          [customername], 
          [dealdate], 
          [amtfinanced], 
          [bounced], 
          [comment], 
          [locationname], 
          [daysout], 
          [datereceived], 
          [dealnumber], 
          [dealershipname], 
          [salespersonnumber], 
          [grossprofit], 
          [make], 
          [model], 
          [newused], 
          [category], 
          [bankname], 
          [customernumber], 
          [finame], 
          [status], 
          [locationname], 
          [datereceived], 
          [comment], 
          [titled], 
          [changedby], 
          [funded], 
          [contractsreturned], 
          [datechanged], 
          citcomment 
ORDER  BY [datechanged] ASC;
```